# Cannot edit value in Tree containing TreeColumns

Tags: java, tree, swt

I'm trying to edit values of individual columns of a `Tree` containing `TreeColumn`s:

```
private Composite composite;
private Composite treeCompositeNdal;
private Tree treeNdalEditor;
private TreeColumn treeNameColumn ;
private TreeColumn treeValueColumn ;

[...]
treeCompositeNdal = new Composite(composite, SWT.BOTTOM);
treeCompositeNdal.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true));
treeCompositeNdal.setLayout(createNoMarginLayout(1, true));
treeCompositeNdal.setVisible(false);

treeNdalEditor = new Tree (treeCompositeNdal, SWT.BOTTOM|SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);

treeNdalEditor.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, false));
treeNdalEditor.setRedraw(true);
treeNdalEditor.setVisible(true);

treeNameColumn = new TreeColumn(treeNdalEditor, 0);
treeValueColumn = new TreeColumn(treeNdalEditor, 0);
treeNameColumn.setText("Name"); treeNameColumn.pack();
treeValueColumn.setText("Value"); treeValueColumn.pack();
```

I have added the selection listener available [here](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FTreeEditor.html).

As I understand, this will only account for the editing of the first column, which is the behavior I'm experiencing. I cannot modify the value column. Does anybody have any experience with this, or any documentation which I might use?

Thank you.

Comment: Just a reminder: `SWT.BOTTOM` is not a valid style for a `Tree` and please use `SWT.NONE` instead of `0` for the `TreeColumn`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If JFace is an option for you, you should consider a TreeViewer with EditingSupport for your columns.
[Ram's Blog](http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/in-place-editing-in-eclipse-treeviewer/) shows you how to do that.

Additionally you should be aware of the following:

> Users setting up an editable tree with more than 1 column have to pass the SWT.FULL_SELECTION style bit.
>   [(see Eclipse Help)](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/TreeViewer.html)